# Is Wizards of the Coast going to continue to release Errata updates on their websites?

Tags: dnd-4e, errata, wizards-of-the-coast

[The last big update for the Errata was back in October](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/updates), and at that time [WotC](http://www.wizards.com/) was updating the errata every month.  Also at the time, WotC was just releasing a new web-based character builder and the new *Essentials* line of products.

Since then, the updates to the Errata have stopped.

Is WotC going to continue to release new errata updates?

Any news on this subject?

Answer (score 4):

In, I believe, one of the WotC podcasts, they stated that they wanted to produce less errata than they had been creating, and that the huge errata list that came out around the time of the 1st essentials books was intended to be a major reset to that end.

[edit]

According to [this](http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Article.aspx?x=dnd/4ro3/20110307#73469) WotC will release typographical and other errors errata monthly, and reserve June and December for more significant errata (read fixing broken and severely bent rules elements).

Answer (score 3):

Updates for online articles will only involve changing the online article itself.  As Wizards will [no longer provide complete magazine downloads](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/26625529/Dragon_and_Dungeon_Compilations), I'm not sure how you are supposed to know something has changed.

Comment: What made your answer become community wiki?

Comment: @MarkRogers You can still mark ANSWERS as CW yourself. Only questions require mod attention.

Comment: @Mark - I did it, I don't feel I fully answered your question and was unsure that I would research further.  I marked this CW to clearly indicate that others can build upon it if they wish.

Comment: Thanks, I'm always intrigued by the mysteries of the 'community wiki'